# How to analyze repeated measures when condition changes at each time point?

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures, experiment-design

I have a dataset from a repeated measures experiment that I am trying to analyze. The experiment had 4 possible conditions. Participants were measured on 1 condition and then again on a second condition. The second condition was NOT the same as the first condition. I want to use contrasts to compare the order of conditions (e.g., condition1-condition2 vs. condition2-condition1) in order to determine whether the order has a significant effect on the DV for one or both occasions.

[image: N responses per condition per occasion]

My approach to analyzing this was with a mixed model:

```
lme(DV ~ condition*occasion, random =~ 1|subject/condition.sequence, method = "ML", data = data)
```

But my supervisor wants me to run it as an ANOVA because that is still the standard method for experiments published in top journals in our field. Given that the design has empty cells and the condition varies within-subject, I don't see how a repeated measures ANOVA would be appropriate.

Am I overcomplicating this? Would a repeated measures ANOVA be appropriate?

Comment: It sounds like you implemented a crossover design. From https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat509/node/123/, "A crossover design is a repeated measurements design such that each experimental unit (patient) receives different treatments during the different time periods, i.e., the patients cross over from one treatment to another during the course of the trial." The analysis is trickier than just doing an ANOVA. Applied Mixed Models in Medicine by Brown & Prescott has an example titled "Four-period, four-treatment cross-over trial" that may be useful.

Comment: Amazing! I haven’t heard of crossover designs before but this seems to be it. Thanks!